# Appending maps as part of group (multiple maps)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a split-frame d3 visual of the world map with some other data points by region. Basically, it's supposed to have the world map repeated several times aligned vertically down the page, with each map highlighting a different continent. Here is my code:

```
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;
var projection = d3.geoMercator().rotate([-10,0]).scale(50).translate([160,100]);

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 310)
    .attr('height', 150);

var topoData = d3.json("world-continents.json");

topoData.then(function(data) {

var continents = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.continent).features;

var map = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'boundary');
var continent = map.selectAll('.continent').data(continents);
console.log(continents)
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
   .range(["#4f81d7","#f6d18b"])
   .domain([3000000,105000000]);

var data = [
  {'continent':'Asia', 't1fg':19, 't2fg':24, 't1fc':758, 't2fc':773},
  {'continent':'Europe', 't1fg':6, 't2fg':37, 't1fc':234, 't2fc':241},
  {'continent':'North America', 't1fg':20, 't2fg':60, 't1fc':102, 't2fc':102},
  {'continent':'South America', 't1fg':-2, 't2fg':22, 't1fc':1, 't2fc':1},
  {'continent':'Other', 't1fg':3, 't2fg':4, 't1fc':5, 't2fc':5},
];

var continentG = svg.selectAll('.cont')
    .data(data)
    .attr('class','cont')
    .enter()
    .append('g');

continentG.data(continents).append('path')
.attr('class', 'continent')
.attr('d', path)
.style('stroke', "#a6a6a6")
.style('fill', function(d) {
  if (d.properties.continent=="South America") {
    return "#003366";
  } else {
    return "none";
  }
});


})
```

The trouble is I cannot figure out how I can repeat the map like I would usually do using an approach like this:

```
svg.selectAll('.cont')
    .data(data)
    .attr('class','cont')
    .enter()
    .append('g');
```

to bind multiple svg objects to data (for example, putting text in a rect, or putting a rect in a circle, ect). Because I have to overwrite the variable `data` with the topojson data needed to draw the map. I was thinking I could have two data calls, but that didn't work. Only one map is drawn, as you may notice from my code above.

### Question

Can I somehow store the topojson geometry so that I can append it to a `g` for use with split-frame maps? Here the context is a different continent is highlighted for each map (in blue).

Comment: Do you want multiple SVGs or a single SVG with multiple groups?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I was going for a single SVG, but if it's not realistic, I'm not ruling out multiples.

Comment: Both are possible, it makes no difference (visually speaking) for the user... I asked just to provide the answer you're looking for. The advantage of multiple SVGs (specially if inside flex divs) is that you can distribute them easier in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution appending multiple SVGs. The advantage of this approach is that you can wrap each SVG inside a div that you can easily distribute vertically (for instance, using `flex`). Here, for brevity, I'm simply using `display: block;`.

You have two enter selections: the SVG enter selection uses your `data` variable:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 150)
```

Then, inside each SVG, the path enter selection uses the downloaded topoJson data (here renamed `mapData`):

```
var map = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(continents)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'continent')
    .attr('d', path)
```

The only complicated part is getting the data from the parent. This can be done with `each`, a local variable or, in this solution, with `this.parentNode`:

```
map.style('fill', function(d) {
    var thisContinent = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().continent;
    if (d.properties.continent === thisContinent) {
        return "#003366";
    } else {
        return "none";
    }
});
```

Here is the demo<sup>*</sup>:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var projection = d3.geoMercator().rotate([-10, 0]).scale(50).translate([160, 100]);
    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
    var data = [{
        'continent': 'Asia',
        't1fg': 19,
        't2fg': 24,
        't1fc': 758,
        't2fc': 773
      },
      {
        'continent': 'Europe',
        't1fg': 6,
        't2fg': 37,
        't1fc': 234,
        't2fc': 241
      },
      {
        'continent': 'North America',
        't1fg': 20,
        't2fg': 60,
        't1fc': 102,
        't2fc': 102
      },
      {
        'continent': 'South America',
        't1fg': -2,
        't2fg': 22,
        't1fc': 1,
        't2fc': 1
      },
      {
        'continent': 'Other',
        't1fg': 3,
        't2fg': 4,
        't1fc': 5,
        't2fc': 5
      },
    ];

    var topoData = d3.json("https://piwodlaiwo.github.io/topojson//world-continents.json");

    topoData.then(function(mapData) {

      var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 300)
        .attr('height', 150)
        .style("display", "block")

      var continents = topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects.continent).features;

      var map = svg.selectAll(null)
        .data(continents)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'continent')
        .attr('d', path)
        .style('stroke', "#a6a6a6")
        .style('fill', function(d) {
          var thisContinent = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().continent;
          if (d.properties.continent === thisContinent) {
            return "#003366";
          } else {
            return "none";
          }
        });
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

---

<sup>* using a topoJson I found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/piwodlaiwo/c0e10c375a7704f18b1bc813bc5eeddb)</sup>

Comment: I like the display block approach for its simplicity, but is there any way to add padding between the maps, so they are not directly on top of each other? Or for example, if I wanted 2 rows and 3 columns of maps?

Comment: Sure, just wrap those SVGs in divs and style them using CSS. As I said, flex is a good option nowadays.